# How to scroll down to new messages on ajax chat?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, chat, instant-messaging

I'm working on a private chat system. I use PHP and Javascript and a lot of frames. :D

```
frames:

-------------*--------------- 

| chat messages here        |                         

-------------*---------------

|send message frame         |

-------------*---------------
```

I want to update the frame where the chat messages are, but I would like to do it cool way. You know if I just reload the frame that don't looks cool. If i just reload a small div, that maybe a bit better, but I don't know... I mean this:

```
function newMessageShow()
{
print messages ... 
// wait 10-20 sec... somehow
newMessageShow();
}
```

You know what I mean, no? ... I'm sorry for my poor english... If you understood me, could you help me a bit?

Comment: Stop using frames and poll your server for new messages with ajax. show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you meant how to scroll down to the bottom of the view use `scrollTop`. I have an example here to see what I mean - http://jsfiddle.net/uPLWT/

Comment: Yeah, I meant show the new messages and scroll down to them... But you know i dont refresh the page i only display a new div with the newest message.. And I have to scroll down to the newest div...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by jQuery ajax post. check this out (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) Has an example to update the div.

Comment: I think it updates only when I click on send button. I want to upload it withouth any event from my side..

Comment: @user1709024 Then use something like `setInterval` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to run every so often and check if there are new messages.

Answer (score 0):

Here ive put together this very simple AJAX chat example, it will poll your server and get the latest 25 messages, it also utilizes the $ajax.post() to send the messages. Messages are stored in sqlite for the sake of simplicity. Perhaps it of some interest.

**The chat page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple AJAX Chat</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
function get_chat(){
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chat_log")[0].scrollHeight;

    $.ajax({ url: "./chat.php", cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data.chat==null){
        }else{
            $("#chat_log").html(data.chat);

            //Scroll to bottom of chat log on new message
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chat_log")[0].scrollHeight;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chat_log").scrollTop($("#chat_log")[0].scrollHeight);
            }
        }
        poll();
    }, dataType: "json"});
}

function poll(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        get_chat();
    }, 1500);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Send message
    $("button").click(function () {
        var text = $("#chat").val()
        $.post("chat.php", { chat: text } );
    });
    poll();
});
</script>
<style>
#chat_log{
    border:solid 2px #ddd;
    background:#ccc; 
    color:#000;
    padding:4px;
    width:500px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<h1>AJAX Chat Polling Example</h1>
<p>Chat Log:</p>
<div id="chat_log">Loading chat...</div>
<p>Send Message:</p>
<div id="chat_send">
    <p><input id="chat" type="text" name="chat" size="42"><button>Send</button></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**The chat receiver/controller and model (chat.php)**

```
<?php 
// A simple table for chat messages
$chat_table  = array("CREATE TABLE chat ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                          user TEXT,
                                          message TEXT );");
// Create a chat store instance.
$chat_store = new chat_store("sqlite:./chat.db", $chat_table);

// User posted to chat
if(isset($_POST['chat'])){
    $chat_store->insert(array(array('user'=>$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],'message'=>$_POST['chat'])));
}else{
    // Grab latest 25 messages 
    $result = $chat_store->get_chat_messages(25);
    // Send as json so jquery can use it to insert into #chat_log
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    // Build an output
    $chat = null;
    foreach($result as $row){
        $chat .= '<p>'.$row['user'].' : '.$row['message'].'</p>';
    }
    //Send the json string
    echo json_encode(array('chat'=>$chat));
    die;
}
//End Logic

/**
 * Chat store class, using sqlite & PDO to store and get your chat messages. 
 */
class chat_store{
    private $db;

    function __construct($dsn,$setup_query){
        $this->dsn = $dsn;
        $this->setup = $setup_query;
        $this->chkSetup();
    }
    /**
     * Connect
     */
    public function connect(){
        try{
            if (!$this->db instanceof PDO){
                $this->db = new \PDO($this->dsn);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
                $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            }
        }catch (Exception $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
    /**
     * Get chat messages
     *
     * @param int $count
     * @return array
     */
    public function get_chat_messages($count){
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM chat LIMIT ".$count;

        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute();
        return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    /**
     * Insert message into store
     *
     * @param array $values
     */
    public function insert($values){
        $this->connect();
        $fieldnames = array_keys($values[0]);
        $fields = '('.implode(' ,',$fieldnames).')';
        $bounds = '(:'.implode(', :',$fieldnames).')';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO chat {$fields} VALUES {$bounds}";
        $statement = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        foreach($values as $vals){
            $statement->execute($vals);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Setup and Create table for store
     */
    function chkSetup(){
        $dso = explode(':',$this->dsn);
        if(file_exists($dso[1])){
            return;
        }else{
            $this->connect();
            //Setup Table
            if(is_array($this->setup)){
                foreach($this->setup as $table){
                    $this->db->query($table);
                }
            }else{
                $this->db->query($this->setup);
            }
            exit(header("refresh:0;url=./"));
        }
    }
}//End Class
?>
```

Comment: Do you know badoo.com? I'd like to make a chat like that... I use jquery scripts.. My problem is only to show the messages in realtime... to get the new messages and scroll down to the new msg withouth refreshing page...